# How to map array of objects to array of plain values in Spring Data Mongo

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-mongodb-reactive

I have a collections of documents, which have an inner array of objects with two fields:

```
{
    "state" : [ 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2022-08-06T00:56:29.615Z"),
            "value" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2022-08-06T00:56:30.615Z"),
            "value" : 2
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to create a projection like this:

```
{
    "$project": {
        "value": {
            "$max": {
                "$map": {
                    "input": {
                        "$filter": {
                            "input": "$state",
                            "as": "item",
                            "cond": {
                                "$gte": [
                                    "$$item.date",
                                    new Date("2022-07-05T00:00:00Z")
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "as": "filtered",
                    "in": "$$filtered.value"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So in result I will get max value of filtered items of array.

However as I see [andApply](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/VariableOperators.Map.FunctionBuilder.html) supports only AggregationExpression. Is there a way to convert simple field reference as AggregationExpression?

It may be accomplished like this, but seems like the last max is redundant:

```
AccumulatorOperators.Max.maxOf(
    VariableOperators.Map.itemsOf(getDatesFilter(onTime)).`as`("filtered")
        .andApply(AccumulatorOperators.Max.maxOf("filtered.value"))
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like we can just construct all "$map" expression via Documents:

```
AccumulatorOperators.Max.maxOf {
    Document("\$map",
        Document(mapOf(
            "input" to getDatesFilter(onTime).toDocument(),
            "as" to "filtered",
            "in" to "\$\$filtered.value"
        )))
}
```